Why memset performance is different for stack and heap memory?
I was playing with benchmarking different programming languages and found an interesting issue. memset performance is different for stack and heap memory. I found no obvious causes for that. For example, the number of page faults is the same, the compiled binary code is the same. The time measured is access time, not allocation time.
Any ideas?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <string.h>

void perf_test(unsigned char* data, unsigned long total_size) 
{
    clock_t begin_t, end_t;
    begin_t = clock();
    
    memset(data, 1, total_size);

    end_t = clock();
    double duration = (double) (end_t-begin_t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;  
    printf("Duration %f", duration);
    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{   
    unsigned long total_size = 1024*1024*1024;

    // Run the program with some argument to run heap test, or without any argument to run stack test
    if (argc > 1) {
        printf("Heap test\n");
        unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*)malloc(total_size);
        perf_test(data, total_size);
        free(data); 
    } else {
        printf("Stack test\n");
        unsigned char data[total_size];
        perf_test(data, total_size);
    }

    return 0;
}

Program output:
./stack_heap.exe
Stack test
Duration 0.125000

./stack_heap.exe 1
Heap test
Duration 0.609000

To compile the program I use the following command:
gcc -O3 -Wl,--stack,1500000000 stack_heap.c -o stack_heap
Update:
Eric Postpischil proposed to run perf_test twice.
Here are the results:
./stack_heap.exe
Stack test
Duration 0.125000
Duration 0.125000

./stack_heap.exe 1
Heap test
Duration 0.609000
Duration 0.125000


Try it with calloc?

I would be surprised if your stack can actually hold a gigabyte of data. You're probably getting lucky here, because the program has no observable side-effects and so the stack allocation can be optimized away.

@paddy: On Linux systems, if your process is single threaded, you can get 1GB of stack. If you aren't ulimit limited, it will grow until it runs into something.

Move perf_test into a separate translation unit. Call it twice in each program execution. State the compiler version you are using, the OS, and the hardware.

gcc -O3 -Wl,--stack,1500000000 stack_heap.c -o stack_heap?  In this case, you don't want optimization at all.  Your use of memset() has no observable effect so the higher the optimization level the more likely it will be elided.

@paddy, see gcc options (the end of the post) for the explanation why I have 1,5 GiB of stack available.

@EricPostpischil. After calling perf_test twice (without moving to a separate translation unit), I get the following results:
Stack test runs fast twice. Heap test: the first run is slow, the second is fast (duration ~stack duration).

@Ry-, with calloc I get the same results.

@AndrewHenle, I added output of 0-th element. So I got observable effect. The results are the same. Moreover, disassembler shows the presence of memset() call .

@IvanBychkov Stack test runs fast twice. Heap test: the first run is slow, the second is fast That strongly applies the stack is fully preallocated and physical pages are mapped to the process stack.  What are the actual memory mappings for each process before and after each test?

Does your compiler have some form of -fstack-check enabled?  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Stack-Checking.html
To prevent jumping over the stack guard page, some compilers with some options will end up attempting to touch every page when moving the stack pointer down for large allocations.  I bet if you check your disassembly carefully you may be able to see this, and therefore your allocation time is being hidden outside of your timer.

Alternatively, the linker stack option possibly puts something in the ELF image that causes the whole stack to be preallocated at startup, though that seems a bit unlikely.

Since, no completed answer has been provided, I decided to post it by myself. This answer is based on provided comments. Especially, by Eric Postpischil and Andrew Henle.
I added sleep calls befor/after each meaningful line of code and used VMMap tool to gather process memory information.
The short answer is the following. If stack memory is used (local variable), all memory is allocated in RAM at once. If dynamic memory is used (malloc), firstly it is allocated in pagefile and then it goes to RAM only after the first memset (in my test case).
The long answer. The key points are the following:

Stack.

After the line unsigned char data[total_size];, both the Committed memory and Working set memory increased to 1 GB.


Heap.

After the line unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*)malloc(total_size); Committed memory increased to 1 GB (Private Data), while Working set memory didn't change.
Additional statement data[0]=123; doesn't make any notable changes.
After the first perf_test() Working set memory is finally increased to 1 GB.
If at this point in perf_test() I call memset(data, 1, total_size/2); instead of memset(data, 1, total_size);, then Working set memory is increased only to 0.5 GB.



Committed memory is a memory which is mapped to RAM or pagefile. Working set memory is a memory which is mapped to RAM.
So, if we get Committed memory, but no Working set memory, then it is mapped to pagefile. Exactly this case occured after malloc and before first memset.
